# How to allow only local connections?

Tags: bitcoind

I've started to implement my bitcoin client to learn the protocol and faced a problem to see debugging output. When I start bitcoind with -debug option, it start to print so many debug messages in such speed that i can't see whats wrong with my client implementation. How can I start the bitcoind program in such way that it will not sync and just listen to new connections from local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
bitcoind -bind=127.0.0.1 -connect=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: strange, when im doing -connect=127.0.0.1 it opens only port 8332, but without this option it also opens 8333 port. I believe that commands like "VERSION" i should send to 8333 port because 8332 doesn't answer me at all.

Comment: You're right. It seems that it goes in RPC mode. Adding `-listen=1` enables 8333. If that doesn't work. `bitcoind -bind=127.0.0.1` should do it.
Let what works for you.

Comment: I meant `bitcoind -bind=127.0.0.1 -connect=127.0.0.1`

Comment: I found another method, run the bitcoind as usual and add firefwall rule  sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --out-interface wlan0 --dport 8333  -j DROP